# Client Browser detection in Vaadin

Tags: browser, browser-detection, vaadin

I want to set different themes to my Vaadin application, depending on the user agent.
In particular I want to distinguish at least between mobile devices (iPhone, Android,...) and desktop web browser.

Vaadin's API reveals two interesting classes:

- [BrowserInfo](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/client/BrowserInfo.html)
- [WebBrowser](http://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/terminal/gwt/server/WebBrowser.html)

`BrowserInfo` seems to do the job perfectly for my needs, but fails on instancing via its `get`-method:

```
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletException: ...
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.BrowserInfo.getBrowserString()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Couldn't find a way to access `WebBrowser` from within my application either.

1. Did I choose the right approach for browser distinction?
2. Why does accessing `BrowserInfo` fail?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As  @quickanalysis pointed out, you've to be aware of the separation of client-/server-side components.

For getting the user agent string on server-side, the following code snippet does the job:

```
ApplicationContext context = this.getContext();
if (context instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
   String userAgent = ((WebApplicationContext)this.getContext()).
getBrowser().getBrowserApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From what class you are trying to call this method? The BrowserInfo is available at client-side as WebBrowser ar the server-side. Take a look at the package naming.

Comment: Pointing me to the differences between client/server components  helped. Thx! (+1 for that)